# Adding scrollview not working

Tags: android, scrollview

Trying to add a scroll view to this layout just for the text, but everytime i do it the text moves to the top of the page. I want the text to stay at the bottom of the page with a scroll view.

Any help please?

activity:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textSize="14sp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `RelativeLayout`. Start with the `TextView` on the bottom, and position the `ScrollView` above the TextView.

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/ll1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    (...)/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    (...)/>

<ScrollView
     android:layout_above="@id/button"
     android:layout_below="@id/ll1"
     (...)/>
```